# Importing a package into Flash

Tags: flash

I'm trying to make use of a package that someone else has written in my Flash AS3 programme. I can't work out how to include it however, nothing I try seems to work. The package is here:

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Accurate_timer-17332.html

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use it on the timeline as shown in the example, or use it in a document class as shown below (OldTimer.as):

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    /**
     * 
     * 
     */
    public class OldTimer extends Sprite
    {
        private var tmr: AccurateTimer
        private var m_time: Date

        public function OldTimer() 
        {
            tmr = new AccurateTimer( 1000, 10 );

            tmr.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, onTmr );
            tmr.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, ontmrC );
            tmr.start();

            m_time = new Date();
        }

        private function onTmr( evnt: TimerEvent ): void
        {
         var newTime: Date = new Date();
         trace( "Timer: ", newTime.time - m_time.time );
         m_time = newTime;
        }

        private function ontmrC( evnt: TimerEvent ): void
        {
         var newTime: Date = new Date();
         trace( "Complete: ",newTime.time - m_time.time );
         m_time = newTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Reference the document class in the IDE via the Properties panel. Select the Stage and the enter the name of the Class eg OldTimer (without the .as extension)

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted with the little tick mark on the left so that others finding this question will know  the solution!